# How to hide/disable google.maps.places.Autocomplete close button?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-3

I have google.maps.places.Autocomplete object and I need to hide or disable "close button X" which appears each time text entered. Much better is to obtain and override "close button" onClickEvent if it is possible at all?

Comment: I don't see any such button [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/places-searchbox). Do you mean the `Infobox` window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the unbinding of events use [`google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapsEventListener). .

For removing of the autocomplete-functionality there is no implemented method. You may create a clone of the input before you create the Automplete and when you want to remove the autocomplete-functionality replace the current input with the clone.

```
(function(ac) {
google.maps.places.Autocomplete = function(node, opts) {
var clone = node.cloneNode(true),
pac = new ac(node, opts);

google.maps.event
.addListener(pac,
'remove',
function(restore) {
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(pac);
google.maps.event.trigger(node,'blur');
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(node);
if (restore===true) {
node.parentNode.replaceChild(clone, node);
} else {
node.parentNode.removeChild(node)
}
});
return pac;

}
}
(google.maps.places.Autocomplete));
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

function initialize() {

autocomplete = new google.maps.places
.Autocomplete(document.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0], {
types: ["geocode"]
});
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&libraries=places&.js"></script>
<input/>
<span>
<input type="button" value="remove input" 
onclick="google.maps.event.trigger(window.autocomplete,'remove');
this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"/>
<input type="button" value="remove autocomplete-functionality" 
onclick="google.maps.event.trigger(window.autocomplete,'remove',true);
this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);"/>
<span>
```